# Checkbox is always "off" or unchecked

Tags: php, html

When I checked my checkbox and click submit, it doesn't work and is still unchecked, mo matter if is checked or not!

```
<label for="checkbox-4" tabindex="4">food</label>
<input type="checkbox" <?php $ch1=strpos($f_type,"1"); if($ch1 >= 0 && $ch1 != ""){echo('checked="checked"');} ?> name="foodtype1" id="checkbox-4" value="1" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show the result HTML code?

Comment: What is `$f_type` ? And do you expect `$f_type` to be something more than `1` or __nothing__ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$_POST['foodtype1'] = 1;
//$_POST['foodtype1'] = 'a';
?>
<label for="checkbox-4" tabindex="4">food</label><input type="checkbox"
<?php if(isset($_POST['foodtype1']) AND $_POST['foodtype1'] == 1) { echo('checked="checked"');} ?>
name="foodtype1" id="checkbox-4" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php $ch1=strpos($f_type,"1"); if($ch1 >= 0 && $ch1 != ""){echo('checked="checked"');} ?> name="foodtype1" id="checkbox-4" value="1" />
```

You should put a space between `<?php ... ?>` and `name="foodtype1"`.

**EDIT:**
Easier test below

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo (strpos($f_type,"1") !== FALSE) ? 'checked="checked" : ''; ?> name= "foodtype1" id="checkbox-4" value="1" />
```